# Saving matplotlib figure from GUI with custum DPI and width

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can't find the way to change the default DPI of the file that I save using the matplotlib GUI for displaying the plot:

[image]

When I save the figure using the icon the DPI are set by default. 
Usually, I use:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
plt.savefig(figurename,dpi=1000)
```

And I got the expected output, but I can't obtain the same output saving the figure from the GUI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using `matplotlib` 2.x, then you [can specify the DPI of the figure when creating the figure](http://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#figure-size-font-size-and-screen-dpi) and that DPI will be used when saving the file via the UI; however, this will also be the DPI which it is rendered at on the screen.

```
fig = plt.figure(dpi=1000, figsize=(4,4))
```

Otherwise, you can set the default DPI for `savefig` in your [rcParams](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#matplotlib-rcparams)

```
mpl.rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = 1000
```

Comment: Note you can also use `plt.rcParams` (no need to import `mpl` separately).

Answer (score 0):

you can set the default DPI for savefig in your rcParams

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = 1200
```